# Issues while starting modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal working well by a button click. But if I show the modal at the end of the , console says:

```
$(...).modal is not a function
```

My scripts in real sequence:

```
    'js/jquery.min.js'
    'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js',
    'js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'js/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.min.js',
    'js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js',
    'js/jquery.nicescroll.plus.js'
```

My Html:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="divConteudoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="height:40px; border:none;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <iframe name="janelaModal" id="janelaModal" style="width: 100%; border: none; min-height: 350px;"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Trigger:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#divConteudoModal').modal('show');
});
```

If I run $('#divConteudoModal').modal('show'); directly at console it works, if I put before /body, as I mentioned above, I get $(...).modal is not a function.

Can you guys see anything that can causing that?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for this issue ?

Comment: Here is the real project: (http://www.comprarmusicas.com.br/index.php?fblogin)

Comment: If you click show source-code, you will see $('#divConteudoModal').modal('show');  at document.ready block code.

Comment: @Swapper any suggestion?